# How to share user certificates to clients

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

Which is the most appropriate way to share client certificates to end users of a Hyperledger fabric network?

I have already set up a java sdk client to Register and enroll users using admin Credentials. At the end of the scenario i have a Username and a Password for each user. What i cannot find is where client certificates are stored at the local MSP and how i can share them to the actual end users.

Any recommendation or example of a proposed solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Currently I am immature w.r.t blockchain, does this link help you? https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#fabric-ca-client

Comment: I know about this link, and at the moment I dont want to use CLI for the certificates but use JAVA SDK instead

Comment: As I have seen, such functionality is introduced in 1.4 version but only for the nodeJs SDK (Identity Wallets). So I think that i have to wait for the java sdk version soon.

Answer (score 0):

while enrolling user,
you will get enrollment object

Irrespective of SDK (NODE, JAVA, GO)

```
let enrollment = await caClient.enroll(request)
const key = enrollment.key.toBytes();
const cert = enrollment.certificate;

response.key = key;
response.cert = cert;
response.secret = secret;
return response;
```

LOOKS like below result

> "data": {   "message": "nbdClient has been enrolled Successfully to
>   Org: nbd",   "key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE
>   KEY-----\r\nMIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgH7ttkV4VIDA1TlSx\r\n/bmsy1Ad6zgLGhjdcFtElexqAtShRANCAASHKIOk+nBTIqfn5taiqMWlRnfHKdth\r\nkZKyq9Up4wl+PsBEQByyKfaDV904APCQ7zDvmPtwxsdNGxA76V4EpAqO\r\n-----END
>   PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n",   "cert": "-----BEGIN
>   CERTIFICATE-----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\nIDkA2OsC0jRswweTHmzGk5z5gKcwhOrZbJTZagqpv2m4\n-----END
>   CERTIFICATE-----\n",   "secret": "HqknKlBGzibb" }